# How to calculate how many customers buy two or more products if all you have is the total number of customers and total customer per product?

Tags: algorithm, set

I have this tough math problem that I've been thinking on and haven't been able to figure out. Have looked into overlapping sets, venn diagrams, combinations, etc.

Let's say there are 2.207 million total customers who may buy between 1 and 4 of the following products: A, B, C and D.

If the customer counts for each product are:

A (2.021 million) (not customers that *only* buy A. These are all customers that have A as at least one of their products

B (650k)

C (1.286 million)

D (176k)

How can I figure out how what percent of the 2.207 million total customers buy at least two products? Is it possible with this data?

Comment: Not clear how this is software / programming related. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Also, you should clarify your comment on A. What does "internet" have to do with your question about "products"?

Answer (score 0):

This question will likely be closed and I initially wanted to leave this as a comment but soon ran out of space.

If your problem has a unique solution (it may not, but if it's a puzzle or exam question it likely does) you can find it solving a system of linear [diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation).

The first step is to break up your set of customers into a partition, that is a group of sets that are disjoint and their union is all the customers.

A simple way to do this is using the following sets

A - customers who only buy A

B - same but for B

...

D - same but for D

AB - set of customers who buy A and B

...

CD - same but for C and D

ABC - customers who buy A, B  and C

....

After you define this partition you can then set up the linear system of diophantine equations using the information provided.

For example, the first equation is

A + AB + ABC + ABCD = 2.021 million

And so on. There should be 5 equations and 12 unknowns. So it is an undetermined linear system, however you only need to figure out the quantity AB + AC + AD + BC + BD + CD + ABC + ABD + BCD + ACD + ABCD, which may be possible by simple algebra.

Comment: It looks like the separation into four different products A, B, C and D is actually mostly irrelevant to the problem, since customers are not constrained in the product they buy (the OP's choice of wording *"customers that have A as at least one of their products"* implies that customers could buy several products of the same type if they wanted).

Comment: So instead, I would write W = customers who buy exactly 1 product; X = customers who buy exactly 2 products; Y = customers who buy exactly 3 products; Z = customers who buy 4 products; and then the equations are W+X+Y+Z = 2.207 millions and W+2X+3Y+4Z = 4.133 millions.

Answer (score 0):

In total, 4.133 million products have been bought by 2.207 million customers, and each customer bought between 1 and 4 products.

Imagine that first we give 1 product to each customer; and then we distribute the remaining products to customers who want 2 or more products.

So, first we give out 2.207 million products. Then, we have 1.926 million products left to distribute.

Here are the two most extreme possibilities:

- No customer bought more than 2 products. Then, there must be exactly 1.926 million customers who bought exactly 2 products, and 281k customers who bought exactly 1 product.
- As many customers as possible bought 4 products. Then, there must be exactly 642k customers who bought exactly 4 products and 1.565 million customers who bought exactly 1 product.

So, the only answer you can give with absolute certitude is that the number of customers who bought at least 2 products is between 642k and 1.926 million.

Perhaps this interval is too big for you. In that case, the next step would be to calculate some kind of average based on statistics. This requires building a probabilistic model that would fit your data.